# special addition on fractions.

Tags: special-functions, fractions

I would like to define a function $\oplus$ on $\mathbb Q$ ($\oplus:\mathbb Q^2\mapsto \mathbb Q$), such that (for all $a,b,c$):

1. (commutativity) $a\oplus b=b\oplus a$
2. (associativity) $(a\oplus b)+c=a\oplus (b\oplus c)$
3. (positivity) $a\oplus b>a$ with $>$ the usual order on $\mathbb Q$
4. (growing) $b>c \Rightarrow a\oplus b>a\oplus c$

Is it possible (For now, I'm sure it is) and how can I give an example of such a function ?

Comment: What do you want to use this for?

Comment: I don't want to give spoiler now, but I think this a hard question, as you may need to use some non constructive math to build such a function.

Comment: Could you please use a notation different from $+$ for this function? I think it is utterly confusing to call a function $+$ when it doesn't even satisfy $a+0=a$.

Comment: I used oplus : $\oplus$. There is a $0$ for this addition, but the $0$ is in fact $-\infty$.

Comment: Do those $>$s have to be strict, or could some of them be replaced by $\geq$ ?

Comment: the functions $x\mapsto a\oplus x$ have to be injective, so you need to be strict. Max would be an easy answer if not.

Comment: Well, $-\infty$ isn’t in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: you're right, it's just if we add it, we can suppose that it behaves like a $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution. The idea came from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518705/is-there-a-bijection-f-mathbbq-to-mathbbq-0) (and the answer from Did).

Let $f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}\frac{1}{1-x}&\mbox{if } x\le0\\ x+1&\mbox{if }x\ge 0\\\end{array}\right.$

$f$ is a bijection from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Q^+$

Let $a\oplus b=f^{-1}\left(f(a)+f(b)\right)$.

Commutativity and associativity are obvious. The other properties come from the fact that $f$ is an increasing function.